# ZF2: How to inject service configuration after all modules are loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am currently building a Theme Manager where each theme are in module format.
These themes are added  in the 'module_listener_options' -> 'module_paths' but not in 'modules' in the application.config.php.

Now, based on the data coming from the database, I want to activate the relevant theme module and enable its controller, service_manager,  and other plugin manager keys, just like any other modules that were added in the application.config.php

I read it online that you can add dynamic configuration using the 'configMerge' event listener (ConfigListener) in ModuleManager, but the ServiceManager and the 'ThemeManager' module (the module that allows to activate certain themes) is not yet fully loaded as the mergedConfig has not gone through ServiceListener yet.

Another suggestion I read is to enable all the modules and then disable the features using listeners. This, I am not sure how to do or if  it actually meets my requirement as there could potentially be a huge number of features per theme module.

Can you dynamically enable modules?

Also, some theme modules are 'child' themes where they inherit the functionality of their parent theme module. I have done the 'inheritance' of the template_path_stack and template_map in view_manager for this, but couldnt do the rest, eg navigation. Did this in 'loadModules.post' event listener within the ThemeManager Module:init class.

I like the idea what WordPress does  with its templates/theme where extra functionality is enable when the theme is activated. Is there anything close to that in ZF2?

If you know any links, readings and pointers that I could potentially have not seen yet, suggestions are very welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: you should look at https://github.com/ZendExperts/ZeTheme - seperate your theme files over multiple modules is a bad idea - make one module and place your logic and template dirs in there

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did! My Theme Manager was actually based on that, but I added some database/Doctrine functionality on top of it so the active theme comes out of the database and picks up the file paths and template stack from the directories. My problem now is how to get the doctrine 'service' launched to "inject" the config array onto the service manager config between the configMerge and loadModules.post events